# Azure devops pipeline nuget restore error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am using azure devops for build and release of azure sql database using visual studio 2019 and have the nuget restore task that's throwing error. We use our own self-hosted agent.

***yaml:***

```
steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    vstsFeed: 'asytrvn-uydrs124yct6'
    
- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build Solution'
  inputs:
    solution: 'myvs.sln'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=AnyCPU /t:Build'
    clean: true
```

***error:***

```
error MSB4226: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" was not found.
```

Comment: You need to make sure SSDT is installed on your self-hosted agent.